# Get the log out of list update Powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, log

I have following powershell to create new list item from a CSV file and it is working perfectly fine in  SP Online environment.

we are making some changes in this list to have the **Title** field hold unique value only...

Now I want to create the log of all successful and failed upload via this powershell script.

I have no clue to this, any help will be appreciated.

```
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://COMPANY NAME.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME"
$ListName = "SAMPLE LIST NAME"
$ImportFile = "D:\CSVFILE.csv"
$User = "USER EMAIL ID"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString

#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

#Get the List
$List = $Context.web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)

#Get the Data from CSV and Add to SharePoint List
$data = Import-Csv $ImportFile
Foreach ($row in $data) {

    #add item to List
    $ListItemInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
    $Item = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)
    $Item["Title"] = $row.Title
    $Item["Department"] = $row.Department
    $Item["EmpIDBH"] = $row.EmpIDBH
    $Item["Location"] = $row.Location
    $Item["IsActive"] = $row.IsActive

    $Item.Update()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery() 

}
Write-host "CSV data Imported to SharePoint List Successfully!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add Try Catch blocks in your script.

For example:

```
Foreach ($row in $data) {

    #add item to List
    $ListItemInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
    $Item = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)
    $Item["Title"] = $row.Title
    $Item["Department"] = $row.Department
    $Item["EmpIDBH"] = $row.EmpIDBH
    $Item["Location"] = $row.Location
    $Item["IsActive"] = $row.IsActive

    $Item.Update()
    try{
      $Context.ExecuteQuery()
     write-host $("successful upload: "+$row)
    }
    catch{
      write-host $("failed upload: "+$row)  
    } 

}
```